# Uncaught Error: Reducer "isClicked" returned undefined during initialization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to set initial state of isClicked in redux but it always throws out this error

Uncaught Error: Reducer "isClicked" returned undefined during initialization. If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly return the initial state. The initial state may not be undefined.

This is my code

reducer

```
export default function reducerDomMethods(state={
isClicked: false,
}, action) {
switch (action.type) {
    case "CLICK_OPEN": {
        return {
            ...state,
            isClicked: true
        }
    }

    case "CLICK_CLOSE": {
        return{
            ...state,
            isClicked:false
        }
    }

        return state;
  }
}
```

action

```
export function clicking(isClicked) {

return function (dispatch) {

            if( isClicked === true){
                dispatch({type: "CLICK_OPEN",isClicked: true});
            }else {
                dispatch({type: "CLICK_CLOSE",isClicked: false});
            }
   }
}
```

combine reducer

```
    import { combineReducers } from "redux"

    import cityName from "./apiReducers"
    import nameOfCity from "./apiReducers"
    import weatherDescription from "./apiReducers"
    import windSpeed from "./apiReducers"
    import temperature from "./apiReducers"
    import maxTemperature from "./apiReducers"
    import minTemperature from "./apiReducers"
    import isClicked from "./manMethodsReducers"

    export default combineReducers({
        cityName,
        nameOfCity,
        weatherDescription,
        windSpeed,
        temperature,
        maxTemperature,
        minTemperature,
        isClicked
    })
```

store

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from "redux"

import logger from "redux-logger"
import thunk from "redux-thunk"
import promise from "redux-promise-middleware"

import reducer from "./reducers"
import reducerDomMethods from "./reducers"

const middleware = applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk, logger())

export default createStore( reducer , reducerDomMethods, middleware)
```

connect

```
import {connect} from "react-redux"
```

@connect((store) => {

```
return {
   nameOfCity:store.nameOfCity.nameOfCity,
   weatherDescription:store.weatherDescription.weatherDescription,
   windSpeed:store.windSpeed.windSpeed,
   temperature:store.temperature.temperature,
   maxTemperature:store.maxTemperature.maxTemperature,
   minTemperature:store.minTemperature.minTemperature,
   isClicked:store.isClicked.isClicked,
  }
 })
```

EDIT:

I was able to correct it(it was a error in store didn't give it specific path to file). but now i get

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined at reducerDomMethods (manMethodsReducers.js:12)

which is this line "switch (action.type) { "

in reducer. I moved the "return " one bracket below(as you previously pointed out)

Comment: You didn't give much info on the actual error. Your `return state;` is inside the `switch`, so I bet you just need to move it one `}` down in the file.

Comment: I was able to correct it(it was a specific error in store didn't give it specific path... but now i get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
    at reducerDomMethods (manMethodsReducers.js:12)   which is this line     "switch (action.type) { " in reducer . I moved the "return " one bracket below

Answer (score 1):

Add a `default` case to your switch and return state from there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return state in default case